# In C#, How do you find out whether an Object is of a Generic Base Type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types

As a part of writing of a code generation tool (client library for my classes), I found an interesting problem.

I have a set of classes:
`SomeClass : MyBaseClass<SomeClass>`
`SomeOtherClass : SomeOtherBaseClass`
`ClassC : SomeCompletelyOtherBaseClass<SomeClass>`

All of `MyBaseClass<T>`, `SomeOtherBaseClass` and `SomeCompletelyOtherBaseClass<T>` inherit from the same base class, but I'm not interested in that one.

Also as the input for my code, I have a Reflected Type (`System.Type`).

What I want to find out is for my Reflected Type - which one of these generic base classes it inherits.

I know it's possible to use the IS operator, or `IsAssignableFrom`, but in this case I don't know what the generic type is.

So I can't just say `myType.IsAssignableFrom(MyBaseClass<T>)`, as I don't know about the `T`, all I have is `MyBaseClass` name.

What I want to get out of this is - be able to use it in a switch/case statement, saying that for all classes inheriting from MyBaseClass do this, for all inheriting from SomeCompletelyOtherBaseClass do that.

Any ideas?

I will however need to identify that the `T` is later down the line, so any additional input welcome.

Comment: Just check if the base type is `typeof(MyBaseClass<>)`.

Comment: Not sure I need empty brackets though? Thanks it didn't occur to me it's that simple :-)
 Now how do I get the type of the T... ?

Comment: `Type.GetGenericArguments()`

Comment: Cool, thanks :) If you post it as an Answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple mockup:

```
namespace Program {

  class MyGeneric<T> { }

  class MyDerived : MyGeneric<String> { }

  class Program {
    public static void Main() {
      MyDerived item = new MyDerived ();
      Boolean isIt = typeof(MyGeneric<>).BaseType.IsAssignableFrom (item.GetType());
      Console.WriteLine (isIt); // Output: "True"

      foreach (Type type in item.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericArguments())
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The only thing is - my input is a reflected Type, not an object.

Comment: Oh, just replace `typeof(MyGeneric<>)` with `item.GetType(...)` -- both return a `Type` object. The only difference is `typeof()` resolves the type at compile time, while `Object.GetType()` resolves it at runtime.

Comment: Thanks :) I love generics :)

Comment: Do I need the empty brackets? "<>" ?

Comment: `I love Generics` -- this x 1000. Unfortunately I work almost exclusively in Java now which has """"Generics"""".

Comment: As for empty brackets: yes you do need them if you want to perform any sort of checking against a generic type for which you do not know the generic parameters. Alternatively, you could use something like `typeof(List<>).MakeGeneric(typeof(String))` which will create the equivalent of `List<String>`, but that requires you be aware of what `T` is ahead of time -- which in your situation, sounds like you don't.